# Simple Open/Closed Restaurant Switch

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple PHP open and closed switch with Radio Buttons... Basically you would come to the page and select wether the restaurant is open or closed, then the resulting echoed value would show on the homepage...

I am struggling with this code I was wondering if someone could give me some insights

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['button1'])) { 
    $txt=$_POST['button1']; 
    file_put_contents('status.txt',$txt,FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX); 
    exit();
}

 ?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
    Restaurant Open:
<input type="radio" name="button1" value="Open" onClick="submit();" <?php echo ($_POST['button1'] == 'Open') ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> /> Open
<input type="radio" name="button1" value="Closed" onClick="submit();" <?php echo ($_POST['button1'] == 'Closed') ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> /> Closed
</form> 

<?php

if (isset($_POST['button1']) == 'Open')
echo "Open Today.";

else if (isset($_POST['button1']) == 'Closed')
echo "Closed Today.";

?>
```

If you need any additional info let me know...

EDIT: Also I need this value to stay in place until someone else comes and switches it.....

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does the code not work at all? Does it do the wrong thing?

Comment: Doesnt seem to work, the value returned is always "Open Today"

Comment: You're comparing an isset to open isset() will return a bool try this `if (isset($_POST['button1']) && $_POST['button1'] == 'Open')`

Comment: Amazing that worked...Also I need this value to stay in place until someone else comes and switches it..... any ideas?

Comment: store value in database or in a text file.

Comment: So I guess a text file will be eaiser... it would be something like this?

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['button1'])) { // check if both fields are set
        $txt=$_POST['button1']; 
        file_put_contents('status.txt',$txt."\n",FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX); // log to test.log (make sure that file is writable (permissions))
        exit();
    }

?>

I have also made edits to my post

Comment: you won't need the \n as you're only writing in a single word/line, you'll also need to remember  to read it back in and do your if switching for the pre-selection radiobuttons if its not set then default to the $_POST input.

Comment: Would you be able to give me a quick example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `isset` returns TRUE or FALSE. Change it:

```
if ( isset($_POST['button1']) && ($_POST['button1'] == 'Open') )
echo "Open Today.";

else if ( isset($_POST['button1']) && ($_POST['button1'] == 'Closed') )
echo "Closed Today.";
```

But using `isset` is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the value in a database somewhere so it is remembered. When you pass it in the form it exists only for your own session.

The homepage should retrieve the value from the database and use it to decide what to display.

Here is an introduction to [PHP and MySQL](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/). It will seem like overkill for just storing a single value but is very useful knowledge for almost any web application.